# Solving $(x-3) (x^2-4x+3) \le 0$, and two others

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Could you help me with 3 quotient inequalities, please?

$$\ \mathbf i \mathbf)\quad (x-3) (x^2-4x+3) \le 0$$
$$\ \mathbf i \mathbf i\mathbf ) \quad (1-x) (x^2-3x) (x^2+x+2) \gt 0$$
$$\ \mathbf i \mathbf i \mathbf i\mathbf ) \quad (x-2) (x^2-3x+2) (x-1) ^2 \ge 0$$

$$\ What\ I\ managed\ to\ solve: $$
$$\ \mathbf i\mathbf i\mathbf )\quad \cdot 1-x\ge0 \quad (=) \quad x\le1\\ \cdot x^2-3x\gt0\quad x(x=3) \ge0 \quad x\le-3 \quad or \quad x\ge0\\ \cdot x^2+x+2\gt0 \quad (=) \quad (x+2) (x+1) \ge0 \quad (=) \quad 1\le x \le 2\\$$
$$\ \mathbf i\mathbf i\mathbf i\mathbf ) \quad \cdot x-2 \ge 0 \quad (=) \quad x \ge 2 \\ \cdot x^2-3x+2\ge0\quad (=) \quad (x-1) (x-2) \ge0 \quad (=) x\le1 \quad or\quad x\ge2 \\ \cdot (x-1)^2\ge0 \quad so \quad (x-1)^2\gt0 \quad for \quad x\neq1 \quad and \quad (x-1)=0\quad for\quad x=1$$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I did the second and the third, but i am not sure if they are correct.

Comment: Please edit your post and add what you have tried. Furthermore check [Math Jax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting the formulas correctly.

Comment: Notice that your first one can be written $(x-3)^2(x-1)\le 0$ and that the first factor $(x-3)^2\ge 0$. Keep in mind that that the original inequality is true if $x=3$ and dividing both sides by $(x-3)^2$ simplifies the problem.

Comment: **ii)** Your factorisation of $x^2+x+2$ to $(x+2)(x+1)$ is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i)It is clear that it can be written $(x-1)(x-3)^{2}\leq\,0$ so it is just $x-1\leq0$ and $x\leq\,1$ or $x=3$.

ii)the term $x^{2}+x+2$ is clearly positive, so it can be written as $x(1-x)(x-3)>0$. In cases like this it is better to draw a diagram like this:

[image]

so the product is positive for $x<0$ and $1<x<3$

iii) it can be written as $(x-2)^{2}(x-1)^{3}\geq\,0$ which is equivalent to $x\,\geq\,1$ or $x=2$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction!